# How to identify records with a specific date in SAS?

Tags: sql, sas

I am new to SAS, and I have a problem with identifying records in a table with a specific date.
I have declared a variable called **fec_diario**.

```
%let fec_diario = 20210423;
```

I have the RATING table:

| cod | const | value | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 321 | 20210413 |
| 2 | 22 | 543 | 20210423 |
| 3 | 33 | 222 | 20210413 |
| 4 | 44 | 111 | 20210413 |
| 4 | 44 | 555 | 20210423 |
| 6 | 66 | 666 | 20210423 |
| 7 | 77 | 216 | 20210520 |
| 8 | 88 | 766 | 20210520 |

And I need to make a query that shows me the clients that have the most recent date, that is, a date less than or equal to the one declared in the variable **fec_diario**.

I achieved this by executing the following code:

```
proc sql;
create table rating_process as
select * from rating
where date <= &fec_diario;
run;
```

And I got this result:

| cod | const | value | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 321 | 20210413 |
| 2 | 22 | 543 | 20210423 |
| 3 | 33 | 222 | 20210413 |
| 4 | 44 | 111 | 20210413 |
| 4 | 44 | 555 | 20210423 |
| 6 | 66 | 666 | 20210423 |

However, if I have more than one record with the same code, I need it to show me only the record with the most recent date..

In conclusion, i should get a table like this:

| cod | const | value | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 321 | 20210413 |
| 2 | 22 | 543 | 20210423 |
| 3 | 33 | 222 | 20210413 |
| 4 | 44 | 555 | 20210423 |
| 6 | 66 | 666 | 20210423 |

It would be very helpful if someone could suggest a solution to my case, thank you very much.

Comment: Does your date variable really have integers like your example value of 20,210,423 ?  Or do they have actual dates (number of days since 1960)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it may work in SAS but may not in other languages:

```
proc sql;
create table rating_process as
select * from rating
where date <= &fec_diario
group by cod
having date = max(date);
quit;
```

Or use a PROC SORT and LAST logic.

Sort so that the largest date is the last record per COD.

```
proc sort data=rating_process; by COD DATE; run;
```

Now take the last record per COD.

```
data want;
   set rating_process;
   by COD DATE;
   if last.COD;
run;
```

Note that SQL requires a QUIT, not a RUN.